# Нужно ли брать лицензию API Яндекс.Карт, если использую их в своей CMS и буду её продавать?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, лицензирование, yandex-geocoding-api, тарификация

Есть проект- CMS интернет магазина, в нем используются яндекс карты для показа клиентам магазина терминалов самовывоза (информация о терминалах берется у курьерской службы). Такой же модуль с терминалами самовывоза есть в админке CMS.

CMS планирую продавать, должен ли я при этом покупать лицензию API Яндекс.Карт?

Если должен то не совсем понятна логика оплаты...
То есть допустим, я купил лицензию карт за 120т.р., продал CMS нескольким покупателям за 5т.р., покупатель CMS (условно) накручивает запросы к картам, а я за них плачу?

Или мне при каждой продаже CMS за 5т.р. предлагать клиенту докупить лицензию карт за 120т.р.

Спасибо.

Comment: CMS, тем более платная, это закрытая система, поэтому она гарантировано требует использовать коммерческую версию.  

Ваш вопрос лучше задать на рассылку paid-api-maps@yandex-team.ru. Этот адрес указан в документации как адрес для вопросов о коммерческих условиях.

Comment: Писал письма по всем адресам- в ответ тотальный игнор. По большому счету, даже не понятно можно ли просто вставить карту проезда в интернет магазин, это же коммерческий проект. Очень интересно у них там работа поставлена.

Comment: В условиях использования нет ограничений на коммерческие проекты, есть ограничение на закрытые системы. Если вы написали в сапорт через форму или по правильному адресу, вам точно ответят. Обычно отвечают в течение суток.

Answer (score 0):

Если API Яндекс.Карт в конечном виде будет отображать карту с объектами на публичной странице информационного сайта, магазина или даже банка, коммерческий ключ для таких задач не потребуется.

Также карта может быть доступна только авторизованным пользователям, если регистрация будет открыта для любого пользователя сети. А вот использование карты в закрытых частях CMS (например в закрытой админке) [условия](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/) бесплатного применения API уже будет нарушать и требовать коммерческого ключа.

Замечу, что Яндекс допускает в качестве исключения изучение API ведение разработки на его основе на локальных машинах и закрытых доменах. Но фактически это нарушает упомянутые условия. И для длительной закрытой разработки, особенно со значительным числом тарифицируемых запросов, правильно использовать коммерческий тариф, либо активированный менеджерами тестовый тариф.